# Cloister monastery convent

Tags: word-usage

Help please. When I have to translate the Dutch word klooster (I have the same problem translating from French but with another word) the dictionary gives me:
monastery
convent,  nunnery
cloister

Unless the text is specific I can't really tell whether it is a monastery or  a convent. Can anyone think of a general term that would cover both establishments without referring to the gender of the inmate?

Comment: I think that at the time these words were coined and used, the gender of the aesthete was very important, so there may not be a term which covers both.  Maybe there has been a coinage in more modern eras.

Comment: It looks like a lacuna. 'monastery or convent'. Note that, to complicate the issue,  a 'priory' is/was  'a small monastery or nunnery' but one that that is 'governed by a prior or prioress' (not, for example, an abbess). [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/priory)]

Comment: Please could you give us the entire sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The word [Abbey](https://www.lexico.com/definition/abbey) is gender-neutral. Lexico gives the definition as:

> The building or buildings occupied by a community of monks or nuns

There is at least one Abbey in England which was founded as a community of both monks and nuns. Whitby Abbey was founded by St Hilda and she was the original Abbess even though some members of her community were men.

I don't think "klooster" in Dutch or "kloster" in German actually have an exact translation in English, the cloisters are specific parts of monasteries, convents, priories, abbeys, minsters, cathedrals and other buildings. Perhaps the dissolution of the monasteries has meant that the modern use of "Klooster" never developed in English. "Abbey" might be the best option.

Answer (score -1):

The Dutch word *klooster* gives a clue:

OED

> **2.a. A place of religious seclusion; a monastery or nunnery; a convent.**

> 1340   Ayenbite (1866) 242   *Lottes wyf betokneþ ham..þet habbeþ hear body ine **cloystre**, an zetteþ hare herten ine þe wordle.*

> 1756   T. Nugent Grand Tour II. 98   *There are several **cloysters** remaining in this city, which are now secularized.*

Comment: This may be a reasonably common usage in the US, but in the UK I'd say it's archaic-to-obsolete and not a good recommendation. The only meaning most would even envisage is the colonnaded walk around a courtyard.

Comment: ... or in an estate agent's property description: *set in a cloistered location* – meaning 'hemmed in'.

Comment: How about monastic community?  (monastic =    relating to monks, nuns, or others living under religious vows, or the buildings in which they live.
    "a monastic order")
By the way is there anyway I can receive a notification that answers to my questions have arrived?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Religious language can be relied on to be archaic to obsolete, and this is the reason why I suggested "cloister". We must look at the context, and I offer *The World Is Our Cloister: A Guide to the Modern Religious Life:* 16 Aug. 2007 by Jennifer Kavanagh (who is English) whose blurb states *"The dedicated religious life of monks and nuns has a fascination for many of us-at a distance.*" Or the book *The Call of the Cloister: Religious Communities and Kindred Bodies in the Anglican Communion."  by Peter F. Anson 1955.

Comment: Not my DV, by the way, though I considered it for quite a few seconds. But not even >90% of those in such institutions will use 'cloister' in this sense. Yes, I'm guessing.